# Stored procedure is fast until it gets called 27 times then ginds into slowness

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, stored-procedures, temp-tables

This stored procedure completes in between 10 - 20 milliseconds (usually) until it gets called 27 times in a load testing session and then it slows way down to 300 - 400 milliseconds per call. There's a clear jump.

After starting over (and running it a couple times with some time between) it's fast again.

What is causing it to jump up so dramatically? How can I get around it?

My requirements are to handle 50 active/concurrent users, but I'm going to blow through that fast if the big call is taking that long.

The stored procedure deals with a parent child relationship. First it clears it all, then it tries to repopulate it from a de-normalized table parameter (faster than nested DB calls in the code).

I would like to remove the FOR loop, but since I don't know the ID of the parent, I don't know how to preserve the FK for the child without procedurally creating the children immediately after the parent is created.

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.sp_DeleteThenCreateRoleAndMembers
    @PenguineHouseRoleMemberUpdate PenguineHouseRoleMemberUpdateType READONLY
    AS
    BEGIN
    -- clear out all the existing roles and stuff
    DELETE PenguinHouseRoleMember
        FROM PenguinHouseRoleMember phrm 
        INNER JOIN PenguinHouseRole ph on phrm.PenguinHouseRoleId = ph.Id 
        WHERE ph.PenguinHouseId = (
            SELECT TOP 1 PenguinHouseId from @PenguineHouseRoleMemberUpdate
        )

    -- cursor setup
    DECLARE @PenguinHouseId int;
    DECLARE @RoleType int;
    DECLARE @SubRoleIds varchar;
    DECLARE @RoleId int

    DECLARE @RowCnt int = 0;
    DECLARE @CounterId int = 1;
    SELECT @RowCnt = COUNT(*) FROM @PenguineHouseRoleMemberUpdate;
    WHILE @CounterId <= @RowCnt
    BEGIN
        SELECT @PenguinHouseId = PenguinHouseId,
            @RoleType = RoleType,
            @SubRoleIds = SubRoleIds
            FROM @PenguineHouseRoleMemberUpdate

        -- insert parent record
        INSERT INTO PenguinHouseRole (RoleType, PenguinHouseId, CreatedAt, CreatedBy, UpdatedBy, UpdatedAt)
            VALUES(@RoleType, @PenguinHouseId, GETDATE(), 'system', 'system', GETDATE())
        SET @RoleId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
            
        -- identify children (subroles)
        DROP TABLE IF EXISTS  #TempSubRoleUpdateTable
        SELECT sq.subRoleId INTO #TempSubRoleUpdateTable
            FROM (
                select convert(int, value) subRoleId FROM string_split(@SubRoleIds, ',')
            ) sq

        -- insert children
        IF (@SubRoleIds IS NOT NULL AND LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(@SubRoleIds))) > 0)
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO dbo.PenguinHouseRoleMember
            (
                workflowinstanceroleid,
                subroleid,
                AllTasksCompleted,
                Approved,
                SuggestedBySystem,
                SelectedByCurator,
                CreatedAt, CreatedBy, UpdatedBy, UpdatedAt
            )
            select
                @RoleId,
                subRoleId,
                0,
                0,
                1,
                0,
                GETDATE(), 'system', 'system', GETDATE()
            from
                #TempSubRoleUpdateTable
        END

        SET @CounterId = @CounterId + 1
    END -- loop
END
```

Comment: There are many opportunitues to tune that procedure to be much more efficient, eg create the temp table *once* at the start and better yet don't use a loop, there's almost never any need.

Comment: If you need a cursor, then use a cursor. So - do you REALLY need a cursor here? and `DECLARE @SubRoleIds varchar;` seems highly suspicious.

Comment: `varchar` with no size? Try this: DECLARE @X varchar='12345'; select X; Result: 1

Comment: @Stu: Thanks. I'm not sure how to take the bottom loop out if there's a parent / child where the child needs to FK to the new parent id.